# How can I copy the URL of a Google search in Safari (after searching via address bar)?

Tags: macos, safari, url, google-search

When I enter `www.google.com` in Safari's address bar and enter a search term in Google's search box I can later copy the URL of that particular Google search from the address bar.

However when I search on Google by directly entering the search term in Safari's address bar, I can never copy the Google search URL from the address bar because the address bar still contains the search terms rather than the Google URL.

How can I copy the URL for a Google search in this instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can drag the magnifying glass icon on the location bar to a plain text view:

[image]

Or run `prompt("",location.href)` in the JavaScript console or run `tell application "Safari" to URL of document 1` in AppleScript Editor.